# Firebase retrieve all where child has specific object

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, querying

I need some help with a Firebase query.

How can I retrieve all users where in the child "groups" a specific group exists?

Every user object in de database looks like this:

```
"067f010c-5580-450a-84ba-6e94880886c2": {
    "goal": 
    {
        "distance": "10",
        "time": "20"
    },
    "groups": 
    {
        "-KH0O99wyxT61xVfjnH5": 
        {
            "group_id": "-KH0O99wyxT61xVfjnH5",
            "name": "Test"
        },
        "-KH0OFDI9jjReE75y7Dj": 
        {
            "group_id": "-KH0OFDI9jjReE75y7Dj",
            "name": "Beest"
        }
    },
    "name": "Arnoud",
    "uid": "067f010c-5580-450a-84ba-6e94880886c2"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be an expensive query as your data set grows. What about having a separate child ('groups') that stores all of your groups and in each group object you keep a reference id to each member that is a part of that group?  Then you can query the data from that direction.

Comment: Thanks for your help, probably thats the better solution.